# Repo command not found while running from Jenkins

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins, repo

When i run `repo init` from ubuntu terminal it is working fine.

Then i created a freestyle Jenkins job which runs on the same ubuntu machine. In execute shell block i added `#!/bin/bash` and `repo init`

[image]

While executing Jenkins Job i am facing following error

`tmp/jenkins10026024406501021323.sh`

`/tmp/jenkins10026024406501021323.sh: line 2: repo: command not found`

Comment: Maybe run "set" or "which repo" and see if it's in your PATH. Otherwise, add it or put a fully qualified path.

Comment: @Kiran : Why do you expect that the PATH is the same in your terminal and inside Jenkins?

Comment: i am not expecting any path, i just want ```repo init``` to work while running from Jenkins.   repo init works fine while running from terminal, but through Jenkins i am facing above error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.bashrc` file was missing, after creating `.bashrc` file and adding  `export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH` in `.bashrc` resolves this error.